# Mongoose: Custom error message for date type validation?

Tags: node.js, validation, express, mongoose

Trying to write a custom error message for Date **type** validation. The way the Number validator works is if it's not a number, the "required" value will act as the default error message:

```
myNum: { type: Number, required: 'Custom error message.' }
```

However that's not the case for date validation, no matter what I try, I get the error message: **Cast to Date failed for value "asdfasdf" at path "start"**

I have also tried a custom validator like this:

```
myDate: {
  type: Date,
  validate: { validator: myFunc, message: 'Custom error message.'}
}
```

But I still get the "Cast to date..." message. I've also tried this:

```
myDate: {
  type: [ Date, 'Custom error message.' ]
}
```

But that just gets interpreted as an array of dates as the type. Suggestions?

Comment: Your example here doesn't have the "required" field in the myDate object, is that intentional?

Comment: related issue : [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3162) and [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4113)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: fwiw this was my solution to capture the error response and change it: `if (error.startsWith('Cast to Date')) { error = 'Custom message.' }` This way I can still use the mongoose validator. Would be nice to be able to set this on my model though.